# Phar архив из проекта на laravel

Tags: laravel, php

Доброго дня!

Пытаюсь создать phar файл из проекта, созданного на основе laravel 5.0. Phar архив со всеми необходимыми файлами создаю, но при запуске, похоже, есть проблема с путями, так что аппликация не запускается как результат. Может, у кого есть подобный опыт создания phar архивов проектов c composer autoload?

Спасибо!

Comment: Так в чем проблема-то?
Что используется в качестве stub?

Comment: P.S.
Там есть вссякие разные функции-хелперы, собственно их и нужно переопределить, чтобы пути на лог оказались вне phar, а настройки пр. внутрь phar. Но там нужно вдумчиво документацию читать.

Answer (score 1):

По личному опыту все дело в правильно написанном stub, начать можно примерно так:

```
<?php

$phar = new Phar("myapp.phar");
$phar->setAlias("MyApp");
# ...
# Тут добавляем все что нужно внутрь phar
# ...
$phar->setStub('<?php
    try {
        Phar::mapPhar();
        include_once "phar://MyApp/vendor/autoload.php";
    }
    catch (PharException $e) {
        error_log("$e");
        exit(1);
    }
    __HALT_COMPILER();'
);
```

Comment: Проблема состоит в том, что при попытке запустить созданный phar архив, он пытается внутри обращаться к файлам с абсолютным путем на диске: phar://{Absolute/Path/To/Folder}/somefile.php. Насколько я понял, это из-за того что в Laravel повсеместно используется __DIR__ . Я пришел к выводу, что в phar архиве нужно использовать относительный путь, а не абсолютный. Но может я не прав.

Comment: Нет __DIR__ в phar-е возвращает и ссылку на phar. То есть путь начинается с phar://, другое дело когда они по каким-то правилам начинают преобразовать путь не рассчитывая на то что он может начинаться на pahr:// - тогда беда, можно в stub-е переопределить spl_autoload и посмотреть чего они пытаются грузить, ну и в vendor/autoload посмотреть чго и как вызывается.

Я преобразовывал простые библиотеки PHPMailer, PHPExcel в phar и все нормально работало.

Если есть простой пример - скин ссылку - посмотрю

Comment: Я сделал простой пример, в стабе делаю загрузку файла index.php, в котором я просто вывожу var_dump(__DIR__) и получаю абсолютный наружный путь, а не внутри phar'a. Phar::mount подтверждает мою теорию

Comment: Собрал phar из laravel там в области автоопределения директории $app['path.base'] возникает засада, при использовании phar $app['path.base'] == '', должно быть $app['path.base'] == 'phar:///path/to/app/sample.phar' по аналогии с нормальным приложением $app['path.base'] == '/path/to/app'


Скрипт которым собирал phar здесь:
https://gist.github.com/chernomyrdin/71188d751b3356f39e48

Comment: Проблема в потрохах PHP :-( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52769

То есть это ошибка realpath, как следствие нужно править использование realpath в \Illuminate\Foundation\Application в методе bindInstallPaths, хотя, я думаю, еще где-нибудь подобное вылезет :-(

Comment: Убрал realpath, в /vendor и в /bootstrap - вроде бы как запустилось, вопрос в том, что дальше нужно laravel лучше знать :-)

Comment: Спасибо! Каждый раз вручную убирать, конечно, не буду. Буду ваять что-то автоматическое. Думал, может, кто-то уже изобрел этот велосипед! Спасибо за помощь!